# Batch file help needed to overwrite existing registry data

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I cannot get the following code to overwrite the string value data if it already has some.

```bash
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Canon\ScanGear\Devices\CNQ2414" /v "InstallDirectory" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\WINDOWS\TWAIN_32\CNQ2414\" /f
```

This asks the question, `Value InstallDirectory exists, Overwrite(Yes/No)?`

If I use:

```bash
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Canon\ScanGear\Devices\CNQ2414" /v "InstallDirectory" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\WINDOWS\TWAIN_32\CNQ2414\" /f >nul 2>&1
```

It supresses the question, but still is waits for a `y` or `n`

Comment: How about removing the incorrect, and invalid trailing backward slash from your string data, which is very likely escaping the adjacent doublequote. ```@%SystemRoot\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Canon\ScanGear\Devices\CNQ2414" /V "InstallDirectory" /D "C:\WINDOWS\TWAIN_32\CNQ2414" /F /Reg:32 1>NUL```. You should also note here, that I used the `/Reg:32` option, instead of using the x86 registry path directly. I also omitted the `/T` option with `REG_SZ`, as those are used by default when omitted. You should also be aware that this modification needs to be made with elevation.

Comment: thanks for trying but
 my windows 11 22h2 message

the system can not find the path specified.

and that would be ok as if already there not need to overwrite BUT now even when there is no such entry same error message and same above error
again thanks for trying its all good gets me also thinking to try on my own others ways. i also tried in run as admin if that what you meant by elevation same cant do

Comment: The code I have given you works 100% perfectly as written, and now tested _(Windows 10)_. If it isn't working for you then your key is being controlled by a user with higher permisdions than standard elevation allows for.

Comment: There are to my knowlege no problems with the use of reg.exe in Windows 11, _(or certainly any which did not exist in the Windows 10 OS version)_. To show you, [here is a screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/BVfgjCn/regMod.png) from just testing it.

Comment: Try: `echo y | reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...`

Comment: @Aacini, whilst that should effectively answer a Y/N prompt, the only way that would be necessary would be if that prompt is not coming from the reg.exe command, or you have knowledge that the `/F` option does not work in Windows 11 version of reg.exe, hrnce not forcing the overwrite. Unless either can be reproduced, my commented code works without issue, when run with elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the /f after the reg key :

`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Canon\ScanGear\Devices\CNQ2414" /f /v "InstallDirectory" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\WINDOWS\TWAIN_32\CNQ2414\"`

Comment: thanks so much is interesting that just changing /f position was it but other entry i added ie. 
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Canon\ScanGear\Devices\CNQ2414" /v "Manufacturer" /t REG_SZ /d "Canon Inc." /f
 works fine the c:\ the difference.
must be alot ov very smart people at stack overflow i surely bet